# Kohen with broken leg and crutches nesias kapayim?

Tags: kohen-priest

A kohen who has a broken leg and needs crutches to support himself can he do birkas kohanim. I remember seeing that if someone is dash biro (seen in town) for 30 days or more then its not considered a distraction .  However, I have also,seen that nowadays since kohanim cover their hands and face With a talis there is no issue of distraction . The difference in this case is that the broken leg is not covered by the talis,so would one need to wait 30 days or not?

Comment: Got to imagine that would be distracting for the tzibbur. Not to mention difficult for the Kohen (to, during davening, quickly unlace and remove his shoes, wash his hands, and afterward put his shoes back on).

Comment: See the Mishnah in [Meg. 24b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.24b.8?with=all&lang=bi) and gemara pertaining to it. (When “dash b’iro”, it’s not that the disfigurement isn’t “considered a mum any longer”, rather the townsfolk have grown accustom to the disfigurement and are no longer distracted by it.)

Comment: You are correct thats what I meant,I have edited it accordingly, tx

Comment: @sam - There is a second issue that you would want to clarify. If he needs support to stand, that would be like sitting, and he cannot do birkas kohanim for that reason. see https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.128.51?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en. Unless he can stand without support when he says the words.

Comment: Besides halachic concerns, there are practical ones: how can he raise his hands (_n'si'as kapayim_) while supporting himself on crutches?

Comment: @sam IAE, see the *gem*. I referenced (wasn’t simply referencing what the scope of “dash b’iro” is) - it quotes an important Beraisa. Rambam, Tos. and others appear to apply “dash b’iro” to deformities mentioned in the Beraisa, not only to eye issues. (FTR, R. Tarfon recanted ([KR 3:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Kohelet_Rabbah.3.11.3?with=all&lang=bi)) that he once ascended to [the] *duchan* with his uncle who was a “חיגר” (lame or had a limp). I don’t have evidence of the extent of his independent walking ability :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a 35-page Teshuva by a Rabbi Dr. Benjamin Lau<sup>(*)</sup> - in Hebrew - sub-titled *Synagogue Inclusion: Can the Priestly Blessing be Recited in a Wheelchair?* that can be read [here](https://www.idi.org.il/media/4251/synagogue_inclusion.pdf).

He concludes that since 21st-century society has accepted people with disabilities, as normal fully functional citizens, hence:

1. They are no longer considered as *inappropriate to be seen in public*. So they may participate in Nesias Kapayim as there's no explicit verse prohibiting them from doing so. (As opposed to the Temple Service that has an explicit verse that a *broken* Cohen cannot participate.)
2. They are no longer a distraction - and there wouldn't be a need to wait 30 days.
3. If they cannot stand they may sit. The prohibition for sitting is only for those who can stand.

From what I understand, his arguments would hold for a kohen who has a broken leg and needs crutches to support himself, as well as one who cannot stand and would have to sit in a wheelchair.

<sup>CYLOR for practical halachic advice; *Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi.*</sup>

<sup>(*) I have no idea who this is.</sup>

Comment: It's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binyamin_Lau but this was pretty controversial see https://www.torahmusings.com/2013/10/rav-lichtenstein-on-disabilities-and-halakhic-values/

Comment: Follow up question - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105945/5275

Comment: He'd have a difficult time getting up the stairs for Shuls where Cohanim Duchan on  elevated stage platform where the Aron Hakodesh is (health and safety come first unless a few people completely get distracted from Davening helping him climb the stairs). The irony is that usually only the more Chareidi Shuls have a level to ground Aron but they definitely wouldn't let him Duchen...