# Can a deaf Cohen duchen?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, birchas-kohanim, deaf

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/105930/5275) indicates that today Cohanim with disabilities may *duchen*.

I am asking here if a deaf person may do so, not because he is disabled, but because he cannot hear the prompt by the Shat"z. Can he rely on either something giving him a hand signal of when to respond or watching his neighbor's lips move? Or does a Cohen's response absolutely require hearing the Shatz's prompts?

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%A9#cite_note-414

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%92

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DoubleAA for the [wikisource](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%A9#cite_note-414) which says regarding a deaf person who speaks but does not hear. (There are various classifications of a "cheresh" in halacha. Most "deaf" people today do not fit into the classical definition of the "cheresh" mentioned in the Talmud which was a deaf-mute.):

> נשיאת כפיים: כהן חרש המדבר ואינו שומע כשר לנשיאת  כפים
>
> A deaf Cohen who speaks but doesn't hear is considered valid for
>   raising the hands (duchen).